# Train neural-net with a sequence ( currently not converging )

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

Due to the recursive nature, I've been able to activate an lstm, which has only 1 input-neuron, with a sequence by inputting one item at a time.

However, when I attempt to train the network with the same technique, it never converges. The training goes on forever.

Here's what I'm doing, I'm converting a natural-language string to binary and then feeding one digit as a time. The reason I am converting into binary is because the network only takes values between 0 and 1.

I know the training works because when I train with an array of as many values as the input-neurons, in this case 1 so: [0], it converges and trains fine.

I guess I could pass each digit individually, but then it would have an individual ideal-output for each digit. And when the digit appears again with another ideal-output in another training set, it won't converge because how could for example 0 be of class 0 and 1?
Please tell me if I am wrong on this assumption.

How can I train this lstm with a sequence so that similar squences are classified similarly when activated?

[Here is my whole trainer-file: https://github.com/theirf/synaptic/blob/master/src/trainer.js](https://github.com/theirf/synaptic/blob/master/src/trainer.js)

Here is the code that trains the network on a worker:

```
workerTrain: function(set, callback, options) {

    var that = this;
    var error = 1;
    var iterations = bucketSize = 0;
    var input, output, target, currentRate;
    var length = set.length;

    var start = Date.now();

    if (options) {
        if (options.shuffle) {
            function shuffle(o) { //v1.0
                for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() *
          i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
                return o;
            };
          }
          if(options.iterations) this.iterations = options.iterations;
          if(options.error) this.error = options.error;
          if(options.rate) this.rate = options.rate;
          if(options.cost) this.cost = options.cost;
          if(options.schedule) this.schedule = options.schedule;
          if (options.customLog){
            // for backward compatibility with code that used customLog
            console.log('Deprecated: use schedule instead of customLog')
            this.schedule = options.customLog;
          }
    }

    // dynamic learning rate
    currentRate = this.rate;
    if(Array.isArray(this.rate)) {
        bucketSize = Math.floor(this.iterations / this.rate.length);
    }

    // create a worker
    var worker = this.network.worker();

    // activate the network
    function activateWorker(input)
        {
            worker.postMessage({ 
                action: "activate",
                input: input,
                memoryBuffer: that.network.optimized.memory
            }, [that.network.optimized.memory.buffer]);
        }

        // backpropagate the network
        function propagateWorker(target){
            if(bucketSize > 0) {
                  var currentBucket = Math.floor(iterations / bucketSize);
                  currentRate = this.rate[currentBucket];
            }
            worker.postMessage({ 
                action: "propagate",
                target: target,
                rate: currentRate,
                memoryBuffer: that.network.optimized.memory
            }, [that.network.optimized.memory.buffer]);
        }

        // train the worker
        worker.onmessage = function(e){
            // give control of the memory back to the network
            that.network.optimized.ownership(e.data.memoryBuffer);

            if(e.data.action == "propagate"){
                if(index >= length){
                    index = 0;
                    iterations++;
                    error /= set.length;

                    // log
                    if(options){
                        if(this.schedule && this.schedule.every && iterations % this.schedule.every == 0)
                        abort_training = this.schedule.do({
                            error: error,
                            iterations: iterations
                        });
                        else if(options.log && iterations % options.log == 0){
                            console.log('iterations', iterations, 'error', error);
                        };
                        if(options.shuffle) shuffle(set);
                    }

                    if(!abort_training && iterations < that.iterations && error > that.error){
                        activateWorker(set[index].input);
                    }
                    else{
                        // callback
                        callback({
                           error: error,
                           iterations: iterations,
                           time: Date.now() - start
                        })
                    }
                    error = 0;
                }
                else{
                    activateWorker(set[index].input);
               }
        }

        if(e.data.action == "activate"){
            error += that.cost(set[index].output, e.data.output);
            propagateWorker(set[index].output); 
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A natural language string should not be converted to binary to normalize. Use one-hot encoding instead:

[image]

Additionally, I advise you to take a look at [Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic) instead of Synaptic. It fixed a lot of bugs in Synaptic and has more functions for you to use. It has a special option during training, called `clear`. This tells the network to reset the context every training iteration, so it knows it is starting from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am so glad I wasn't alone in finding problems with Synaptic! I tried fixing it and even contacted the author who wasn't much help, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Why does your network only have 1 binary input? The networks inputs should make sense. Neural networks are powerful, but you are giving them a very hard task.

Instead you should have multiple inputs, one for each letter. Or even more ideally, one for each word.

Comment: because it is a rnn so it takes 1 part of the sequence at a time and remembers the sequence